# Quotes text regex that ignores backslashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I need a regex that would get all the text inside quotes ( **"**, **'** )
For Example:

```
import re
i = 'Test Text 1 "Test Text 2"'
re.compile(regex).findall(i)
# Returns: ['"Test Text 2', '"']
```

Till now, I've made this regex:

```
regex = ("(')([^']+)?|(\")([^\"]+)?")
```

And this works pretty well, tho there is a problem. I want it to work like python quotes color coding system, so I want it to not stop the element if there is a backslash before the end quote.
For Example:

```
import re
i = 'Test Text 1 "Test Text \\" 2"'
re.compile(regex).findall(i)
# Returns: ['"Test Text " 2', '"']
```

Comment: Does this hyphothetical regex need to *ignore* the backslash-before-quote if there are *two* backslashes? (.. Actually *any* even number of backslashes.)

Comment: no. If its `'"Test Text \\\\"'` then it should not ignore it, as I said, exactly like python quotes color coding. Basically as you said, even number of backslashes shouldn't be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
import re
i = 'Test Text 1 "Test Text \\" 2"'
regex = r"(['\"])((?:\\.|(?!\1)[^\\])*)\1"
print( re.compile(regex, re.DOTALL).findall(i) )
# => [('"', 'Test Text \\" 2')]
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Dy6UKN/2) and [Python demo](https://tio.run/##RYyxCsIwFEX3fMUzS94TCUQ3QYrgWHDJ1ldBNGqgTULMUMF/j9XF8R7OuelVHjFsavVjirlAdsLDDpR1zwLWTQUMyP9glrCWSmR3d9PsZYmdYtkTYrNl1m9sFmyoOzH3tCQ2UqTsQ8H5WF/imPzg8BevvuRwtPu2JX3z4XoeBvQEJGr9AA).

The `(['"])((?:\\.|(?!\1)[^\\])*)\1` pattern matches any quote in Group 1 and then matches any escape sequence (with `\\.`) or any character other than the quote captured and backslash (`(?!\1)[^\\]`), zero or more times, up to the quote captured (see `\1`).

Comment: Thanks. This works, but when there isn't an end quote, it claims the quote with the backslash behind it as the end quote. For example: i = 'Test Text 1 "Test Text \\" 2'